# Why is Bootstrap styling lost in my sidebar?

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap dashboard (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/dashboard) as a base for my project.

I have added form in the sidebar but 'bootstrap' styling is lost as you can see in picture below.

I have tried different approach like crispy-form (what I currently use), django-widget-peaks, but result is not really good I think, maybe because part of CSS is override?

For example, text in the "Select" is partially visible...
I would like to be able to use bootstrap styling option like input-group-sm to decrease input size but it doesn't works...

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask]. You haven't provided enough information. You should share some rendered HTML and the Bootstrap library (CDN link) in a snippet demo. Also, please don't tag post titles.

Comment: cant help You without code.!